# Imported database to local Magento install from prior SQL dump, now unable to access, always redirects to live site (dumped) URL?

Tags: magento-1.9

Imported database to local Magento install from prior SQL dump in order to restore products gone missing and export to import to live site. However now when I try accessing the local site it redirects to the live site. Where in the database can I disable this?

Answer (score 1):

Check the **core_config_data** table where **path** = `web/unsecure/base_url` and `web/secure/base_url`.

There you can change the base URLs of your site.

(They are usually in the 2nd and 3rd row of this table)

Comment: Thank you. Also my admin URL locally is different from that of the database I imported, and when I try accessing it I get an "error processing [my] request", and when I try the imported site's admin URL I get a 404. Do you know how I can manage to access the admin?

Comment: You need to use the new admin URL to access it. You can check the details of the error in /var/reports/number_of_report (you can see the number of report on your browser screen in the "error processing your request"). You should delete entire contents od /var/cache and var/session folder. They might be causing this error. If not, then post the error from the report.